# How to join multiple tables without relationship

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join, hibernate-criteria

This is my 1st project in Java/Hibernate.

I m trying to join two tables but even after searching a lot, I couldn't find the proper solution to achieve what i want.

Let me explain you what i have currently.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admin")
public class AdminLogin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String status;
    private String userRole;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_balance_log")
public class UserBalanceLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int userId;
    private int adminId;
    private Float balance;
    private String balanceType;
    private String message;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreated;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getAdminId() {
        return adminId;
    }

    public void setAdminId(int adminId) {
        this.adminId = adminId;
    }

    public Float getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(Float balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public String getBalanceType() {
        return balanceType;
    }

    public void setBalanceType(String balanceType) {
        this.balanceType = balanceType;
    }
}
```

I want to join the adminId from User Balance Log Entity to Admin Login Entity.

This is what i have currently.

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBalanceLog.class, "ubl");

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("balance"),"balance").add(Projections.property("balanceType"),"balanceType").add(Projections.property("message"),"message").add(Projections.property("dateCreated"),"dateCreated"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));       

if (parameters.get("userId") != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", new Integer(parameters.get("userId"))));
}

if (parameters.get("balanceType") != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("balanceType", parameters.get("balanceType")));
}

if (parameters.get("dateCreated") != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("dateCreated", parameters.get("dateCreated")));
}
List userBalanceList = criteria.list();
```

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply add the "@ManyToOne" annotation to your entity and the a @JoinColumn(name="adminid") even without having a FK(it's a bit risky tho, because if your data is inconsistent, you're gonna get an error doing so. The alternative would be mapping your field with @Formula.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: First example:

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="adminid")
       private AdminLogin adminLogin; //with proper getters and setters

Second example:

       @Formula("select a.id from admin a,user_balance_logs ubl where a.id = ubl.adminid")

Comment: If i use this, @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="adminid") private AdminLogin adminLogin; //with proper getters and setters

How will i save integer id in adminId column?

Comment: you can either create a new AdminLogin with just the primary key set, and JPA will automatically recognize if it's an existing key or not, OR you can set that field as READ only and just leave the adminId as an int.

Comment: Ok so based on this @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="adminid") private AdminLogin adminLogin; //with proper getters and setters,

What modifications do i need to do in the criteria code that i have currently?

Comment: Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBalanceLog.class);
 criteria.setFetchMode("adminLog", FetchMode.JOIN);
 List list = criteria.list();

Comment: I m getting this error now: could not resolve property: adminLogin of: org.jasyatra.model.UserBalanceLog

Comment: Based on your suggestion, i did this criteria.createAlias("ubl.adminId", "a"); and it made it work

Thanks

Comment: Since i m fetching the required columns only, i m getting response like this:

{
    "result": "true",
    "data": [
        [
            2345,
            "debit",
            "test",
            "2019-04-19",
            "admin"
        ]
    ],
    "start": 1,
    "totalrecords": 0
}

I don't see column names, i directly get data. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Once i did this, criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);, it worked too. 

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Sorry i couldn't answer until now, I was busy at work :D I'm glad you finally figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out myself of course with the help/guidance of @vc73.

This is the updation i had to do in model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_balance_log")
public class UserBalanceLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="adminId")
    private AdminLogin adminId;

    private Float balance;
    private String balanceType;
    private String message;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreated;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public AdminLogin getAdminId() {
        return adminId;
    }

    public void setAdminId(AdminLogin adminId) {
        this.adminId = adminId;
    }

    public Float getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(Float balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public String getBalanceType() {
        return balanceType;
    }

    public void setBalanceType(String balanceType) {
        this.balanceType = balanceType;
    }
}
```

and in the DAO:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBalanceLog.class, "ubl");
criteria.createAlias("ubl.adminId", "a");

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("balance").as("balance")).add(Projections.property("balanceType").as("balanceType")).add(Projections.property("message").as("message")).add(Projections.property("dateCreated").as("dateCreated")).add(Projections.property("a.username").as("username")));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));

if (parameters.get("userId") != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", new Integer(parameters.get("userId"))));
}

if (parameters.get("balanceType") != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("balanceType", parameters.get("balanceType")));
}

if (parameters.get("dateCreated") != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("dateCreated", parameters.get("dateCreated")));
}

criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

criteria.setFirstResult(start);
criteria.setMaxResults(Pagination.limitPerPage);
List userBalanceList = criteria.list();
```

I hope it will help someone else.